# How to pin/unpin ParseObject non recursive?

Tags: parse-platform, local-datastore, parse-android-sdk

In my new android app based on parse, I would prefer pinning all sub-elements myself / not automatically, as pinning a certain sub-element would result in infinite recursion or just does not make sens in my context.
Is there a way to pin and unpin an object not recursively?

I am already able to pin an object not recursively, but it is not such a pretty way:

```java
Method m = ParseObject.class.getDeclaredMethod("pinInBackground", String.class, boolean.class);
m.setAccessible(true);
Object object = m.invoke(parseobject, pintag, false);
if(object instanceof Task) {
   Task task = (Task) object;
   return task;
}
```

Is there any normal way to achieve this?
And is it somehow possible to unpin an object without this recursion mentioned in the Javadoc?

```
Removes the object and every object it points to in the local datastore, recursively.
```

Comment: I am afraid currently there is no way to do that. But you should open an issue at Parse Android SDK Repo since I think it is something easy to be implemented.

Comment: I am currently trying to implement this. Thank you for confirming that I have missed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is apparently at the time no solution for my problem implemented in the [Parse-SDK-Android](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android),
I implemented some functions myself.

Currently the [pull request](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/pull/963) is still not merged.
If someone needs a fast solution, feel free to use [my branch](https://github.com/thomax-it/Parse-SDK-Android/tree/non-recursive-pinning):

```
implementation 'com.github.thomax-it.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.21.1'
```